# Is there a pre-built clang library for Windows?

Tags: windows, dll, clang

I am developing a tool using the clang library on Linux and I would like to port this tool to Windows.

On Linux,  I can install Clang from the LLVM repositories using `apt-get clang-6.0-dev` and simply link my tool with `-lclang`. I do not need to compile LLVM and Clang myself.

Is there a way to do something similar on Windows, or do I need to compile the Clang library myself?

All of the Clang-related posts I could find are about using clang as a tool,  not as a library.

I have installed the pre-build executables for Clang and LLVM from the LLVM website,  and these work nicely in combination with mingw. However, the download for Windows does not seem to include the Clang library as a separate file (DLL), and linking with `-lclang` results in a linker error.

If there is no pre-built library for Windows, what is the best way to proceed, preferably using mingw and not MSVC?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the prebuilt binaries here? http://releases.llvm.org/download.html

Comment: @DaveNottage this page do not contain libclang libraries, just binaries.

Comment: At the moment of writing, the official release at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases contains libclang.dll as well as include files, for example at `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\libclang.dll`, so if you have clang installed, you should also have libclang.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are pre-built LLVM/clang binaries on [Zig](https://github.com/ziglang/zig)'s github page:
https://github.com/ziglang/zig/wiki/Building-Zig-on-Windows

You can find `libclang.dll` in the `bin` folder.

The currently available versions are:

- `llvm+clang-6.0.0-win64-msvc-release.tar.xz`
- `llvm+clang-7.0.0-win64-msvc-release.tar.xz`
- `llvm+clang-8.0.0-win64-msvc-release.tar.xz`
- `llvm+clang-9.0.0-win64-msvc-release.tar.xz`
- `llvm+clang+lld-10.0.0-x86_64-windows-msvc-release-mt.tar.xz`

There are also detailed build instructions, [here](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/wiki/How-to-build-LLVM,-libclang,-and-liblld-from-source).

Comment: The links at the time of this comment only show llvm+clang-9.0.0, please could you direct me to version 6.0.0? I need this specific version for my Haskell compiler.

Comment: @AboAmmar the 6.0.0 zip is still available - just replace the current zip name with the one from above in the download link

Comment: Thank you @valiano, this link worked: https://ziglang.org/deps/llvm+clang-6.0.0-win64-msvc-release.tar.xz, you saved my day.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me some work :p

Answer (score 12):

For anyone coming to this question that's just looking to install `libclang` on their system, the [choco llvm package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/llvm) appears to install `libclang` correctly. I can't speak to whether this is adequate for actually linking against this library for C/C++, but it worked for my case.

Just run this in an elevated command prompt or powershell:

```
choco install llvm
```

You may need to run `refreshenv` or open a new console for tools to pick this up.

In my case, and to help with future googlers (since I couldn't find a simple answer elsewhere) my issue was specifically while trying to compile a Rust project that made use of the `onig_sys` crate:

```
   Compiling onig_sys v69.2.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `onig_sys v69.2.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `[redacted]\target\debug\build\onig_sys-b53394f57ee5e2c5\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
cargo:warning=couldn't execute `llvm-config --prefix` (error: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2))
cargo:warning=set the LLVM_CONFIG_PATH environment variable to a valid `llvm-config` executable

--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to find libclang: "couldn\'t find any valid shared libraries matching: [\'clang.dll\', \'libclang.dll\'], set the `LIBCLANG_PATH` environment variable to a path where one of these files can be found (invalid: [])"', src\libcore\result.rs:1188:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

After installing `llvm`, the `cargo build` finished successfully